# Is it safe to call dlclose(NULL)?

Tags: linux, posix, dynamic-loading, dynamic-library, shared-libraries

I experience a crash when I pass a `null` pointer to `dlclose`.

Should I check for null before calling `dlclose`?

POSIX tells nothing about this:
http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/7908799/xsh/dlclose.html

Is it undefined behaviour or a bug in `dlclose` implementation?

Answer (score 5):

This is tricky. POSIX states that

> if `handle` does not refer to an open object, `dlclose()` returns a non-zero value

from which you could infer that it should detect, for an arbitrary pointer, whether that pointer refers to an open object. The Linux/Glibc version apparently does no such check, so you'll want to check for `NULL` yourself.

[Aside, the Linux manpage isn't very helpful either. It's quite implicit about `libdl` functions' behavior, deferring to POSIX without very clearly claiming conformance.]

Answer (score 1):

It also says nothing about being accepting a `NULL` and *not* crashing. We can assume from your test that it doesn't do an explicit `NULL` check, and it does need to use the pointer somehow to perform the closing action … so there you have it.

Comment: "If the object could not be closed, or if handle does not refer to an open object, dlclose() returns a non-zero value." I also crashes if I pass any arbitary value.

Comment: Yes—the above line seems to be predicated on the notion that the handle does refer to an object that was once returned from `dlopen()`.

Comment: What if dlopen returns 0? Is it safe to call dlclose(dlopen())?

Comment: I did say "an object", rather than "`NULL` in the case of error".

Answer (score 1):

Following the `malloc`/`free` convention (1), it is a bug. If it follows the `fopen`/`fclose` convention (2) it is not. So if there is a bug, it is in the standard because it lacks convention for dealing with zombies.

- Convention (1) works well with C++11 move semantics
- Convention (2) leaves more responsibility to the caller. In particular, a dtor must explicitly check for null if a move operation has been done.

I think this is something that should be revised for an upcoming POSIX revision in order to avoid confusion.

---

### Update

I found from this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/6277781/877329, and then reading `man pthread_join` that you can call `pthread_join` with an invalid tid, supporting the `malloc/free` convension. Another issue I have found with the dynamic loader interface is that it does not use the standard error handling system, but has its own `dlerror`function.

Comment: Any documentation stating that you can call `pthread_join` with an invalid thread id is wrong. This was an outstanding issue for a long time in the docs but was finally fixed a few years back. The linked answer stating that you can has been deleted by the author as being wrong.