# Passing null to dlclose()

Tags: c++, c, unix, dlclose

Is it safe to pass null (`0`, `NULL`, `nullptr`, ..) to `dlclose()`?

I could not find anything regarding this in the [manual](https://linux.die.net/man/3/dlclose).

Comment: FYI: [SO: Is it safe to call dlclose(NULL)?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11412943/7478597)

Comment: Darn... I looked but still missed it. Time to close this as a duplicate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it is not documented, it is most likely not (or at "best" undefined).
Actually a simple test could verify that for your platform:

Compiling this

```
#include <dlfcn.h>
int main()
{
   dlclose(0);
}
```

Already yields the following compiler warning (gcc):

```
test.c: In function ‘main’:
test.c:5:2: warning: null argument where non-null required (argument 1) [-Wnonnull]
    5 |  dlclose(0);
      |  ^~~~~~~
/usr/bin/ld: /tmp/ccYF9oqz.o: in function `main':
```

An running it, crashes as expected with a segmentation fault.

Why you want to do or need to know this in the first place is the question.
It should be trivial to do a null-check before calling `dlclose` or provide
a wrapper that does it, if otherwise inconvenient.

Comment: Well, it ***is*** declared as `extern int dlclose (void *__handle) __THROWNL __nonnull ((1));` on my Ubuntu 20.04 installation....

Comment: Yeah, hence the compiler warning (that is where I tested it BTW).

Answer (score 1):

It is **not** safe.

Looking at the glibc implementation, the handle passed to this function is a pointer to a `struct link_map` instance.  This pointer is then dereferenced without a NULL check.

So you need to check for NULL before calling `dlclose`.